# Read and process a batch of messages from Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, apache-kafka-streams

I would like to read a batch of messages from a kafka topic and at regular time intervals, or when the number of messages read reaches a certain number, send them as a batch to a downstream system. At the moment my kafka topology is terminated by a processor which holds the messages and then processes the batch incrementally using the punctuate method.

I'm not sure this is perfect, however, because if the application crashes before the punctuate method is called, I think some messages get lost (i.e. the consumer thinks it has finished with them but they won't appear in the downstream system).

```
batchQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>(batchSize);

KStream<String, String> inputStream = builder
    .stream(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String(), "source-topic")
    .process(new ProcessorSupplier<String, String>() {

            @Override
            public Processor<String, String> get() {
                return new AbstractProcessor<String, Wrapper>() {

                    @Override
                    public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
                        super.init(context);
                        context.schedule(flushPeriod);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void process(String key, String value) {
                        batchQueue.add(value);
                        if (batchQueue.remainingCapacity() == 0) {
                            processQueue();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void punctuate(long timestamp) {
                        processQueue();
                        context().commit();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void close() {}
            };
        }
    });
```

- Is there a way to make this approach more robust? Perhaps windowing but I don't really understand this.
- Do I have to use Kafka connect for this. I'm leaning away from this due to it's error handling capability: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/confluent-platform/OBuLbVHbuyI

Comment: Can you clarify, why you want to "batch" your data, instead of processing it continuously? If you want to guard against data loss, you will need to attach a state to your processor: http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide.html#defining-a-state-store I am also curious what you don't understand with regard to windowing? Maybe you should ask in Confluent Community slack channel (https://confluentcommunity.slack.com/) or at users@kafka.apache.org.

Comment: Btw: you program would break if you run multi threaded as all threads would share the same queue object. The queue variable should be a member of the Processor you define!

Comment: I would like to batch my data as the push to the downstream system is quite expensive and is much more efficient as a push of 100 items instead of 100 pushes of 1 item. The bit i dont understand is how to produce a window of 100 items instead of a window of time. I will check out the slack channel.

Comment: In Kafka, windows don't store the raw input value, but the current aggregate that get's updated each time a new record is added to the window. Thus, windows, will not help. You will need to attach a store to your Processor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to make this approach more robust? Perhaps windowing but I don't really understand this.

I'd recommend to decouple the data transformation part (for which I'd use Kafka's Streams API) and the data ingestion part where you write to your downstream system (for which I'd use Kafka's Connect API).

In short, why should your transformation logic be coupled with and need to worry about the specifics (here: expensive inserts!) of one of the downstream systems that this data will eventually be forwarded to?  The responsibility of the transformation should ideally be transformation only, and it should not be concerned with operational aspects of an external, downstream system.  If, for example, you eventually wanted to forward the transformed data into a second downstream system (or a third, ...), then a coupled approach would mean you'd have to update/redeploy/... your application, even though none of its transformation logic changed.

Another benefit of decoupling transformation and ingestion is that your transformation logic will be much simpler because it does not have to account for failures due to the downstream system(s) being slow, unavailable, etc. For example, it does not need to implement/test a complicated retry logic.

> Do I have to use Kafka connect for this.

No, you don't need to use Kafka Connect for this, but it's arguably the best tool for this task.

> I'm leaning away from [Kafka Connect] due to it's error handling capability: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/confluent-platform/OBuLbVHbuyI

In the latest versions of Kafka Connect, the error handling is actually pretty good.  Also, the problem in the linked discussion can IIRC easily be solved by providing a more robust converter (think: serializer/deserializer) for Connect to use.

Also, as mentioned in that link, the specific problem that was discussed there becomes much less of an issue when you validate compatibility of data before it is written to Kafka.  You can achieve this by leveraging Confluent's schema registry (https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry, [docs](http://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/docs/) or similar tools.  Since you raised the question "how can I make this more robust", thinking about [data serialization and evolution](http://docs.confluent.io/current/avro.html) is another important aspect I'd look at before deploying to production.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Miguno, thanks for the insightful answer. I seem to have come to the same conclusion independently (yay me) which is a good sign. We are using the StringConverter (which as you point out is more robust) with routing to error topics if the deserialization goes wrong (before sending the batch to the downstream dependency).